# How To sync SharePoint Tasks with Outlook using custom code?

Tags: c#, outlook, sharepoint-2013

To sync SharePoint Tasks with Outlook, we can use "Connect to outlook". This option provides us with two way synchronization.

**Issue:** The requirement is to create a custom form, which retrieves and updates the items in the task list and then to add this form as an add-in for Outlook. This form contains a tree view control with nodes like *All Tasks, AssigendToMe, AssignedByMe* nodes and my logic to fetch the count of tasks for each node. When I click on a node, the respective tasks of each node will be displayed in a grid view.

Can someone, please kindly suggest how to achieve this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!